# ASP.net/IIS runtime environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm not too experienced in the regard of configuring IIS/ASP.net. A client has asked me to extend the functionality of a custom web application I didn't develop. Unfortunately, they don't have the original Visual Studio project/source code. I'm trying to pull the application off of their production IIS server and configure it for development on my machine. I've already setup a new website instance in IIS on my machine and copied the code to it's directory. When I access it (`http://localhost`), I'm currently receiving a null reference in the application. Obviously, this is a pretty generic error the can be caused by a bug, but I feel it's related to IIS's configuration. I've made sure both sites are using the same .NET version and they are also both running in integrated pipeline mode. Any ideas on what else I should look into?

Production server: Server 2008 R2 (64bit), IIS 7.5 Development machine: Win7 (64bit), IIS 7.5

Comment: This is a pretty broad topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an implementation issue.  It potentially would be on-topic at another SE site but does not provide enough information for a meaningful answer to be written.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I agree this was a broad question - if it's worth anything in the future, check the connection strings too. I forgot ASP.net would be connecting to most of these datasources on startup. This/bad error handling was the issue in my case.